# Building React app for production throwing error in the react router dom v6.4 library

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

The app is build using Vite, and it's a React ts based app. The project runs normally in development mode, but when trying to build the app for production using `npm run build`, getting below error.
I really don't want to degrade the react-router-dom version below 6.4
[image]

```
 [commonjs--resolver] Unexpected token (656:59) in /Users/sanketsaha/Work/School/TulipApp/node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js file: /Users/sanketsaha/Work/School/TulipApp/node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js:656:59 654: 
 655:     if (typeof document === "undefined") { 656:       throw new Error("You are calling submit during the server render. " + "Try calling submit within a `useEffect` or callback instead.");
                                                                    ^ 657:     } error during build: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (656:59) in /Users/sanketsaha/Work/School/TulipApp/node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js
        at pp$4.raise (file:///Users/sanketsaha/Work/School/TulipApp/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:20114:13)
        at pp$9.unexpected (file:///Users/sanketsaha/Work/School/TulipApp/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:17415:8)
```

Can someone please guide me here. Unable to resolve the error.

Comment: Seems you are calling "submit" during the render, e.g. an unintentional side-effect. Have you tried doing what the error message informs you to do? We can't address issues with code we can't see though, so can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] of the code you are trying to use?

Comment: The app works fine in development mode, but once i build the app for prod, it throws error. Added package.json image for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the error. It was encountered due to the server configuration in  `vite.config.ts`.  It is going to get served as static pages from dist folder.